# How to check if deletion is caused by CASCADE in PostgreSQL trigger

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql, cascading-deletes, postgresql-9.3

In PL/pgSQL trigger function, is there a way to know that the deletion was invoked by  cascading delete action?
I have a number of checks in a trigger function to see if deletion is allowed, which I don't want to perform if the deletion is cascading from master table.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I can't think of a built-in way to check that.
You could *instead* check for existence of the master row in the master table ...

```
IF EXISTS (
   SELECT 1
   FROM   master_table m
   WHERE  m.master_id = OLD.master_id) THEN

   -- run checks

END IF;
```

If it's a cascading delete the master row should be gone already.

Comment: Of course! I should have thought of that. I will try it now.